# PDF Reading in UIWebView with horinzontally in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

For Reading PDF file in `UIWebView` with horizontally in iOS.

So i write following to add with `UIScrollView` to scroll horizontally.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 420);
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [scrollView addSubview:self.spiderWeb];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [self.spiderWeb loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

It doesn't showing anything. Without ScrollView , i can read PDF in UIWebView with vertically. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below links may be it is useful for you

https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PrintWebView/Introduction/Intro.html

http://www.labs.saachitech.com/2012/10/23/pdf-generation-using-uiprintpagerenderer/

Comment: That is not what i need brother. I need to scroll horinzontally when reading PDF in UIWebView.